# Python, the same "for" for two lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have two lists

```
a: a, b, c, d, e
b: blue, white, brown, yellow, red
```

I need a to become blue's key in a dictonary, so i need to do this:

```
dictonary[a]="blue"
```

but how do I do it using the same for...

Comment: how about a simple loop? it's not an elegant solution, but it works...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) to merge `a` and `b`:

```
dict(zip(a, b))
```

Because the `dict()` constructor also can take a sequence of (key, value) pairs no for loops are needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to loop over the lists concurrently, you can loop over indices:

```
dictionary = {}
for i in range(min(len(a), len(b))):
    dictionary[a[i]] = b[i]
```

If you just want to achieve the result described, it is better to do what [Martijn Pieters said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12081163/159388) and use `dict(zip(a, b))`

Comment: .. or use `min(len(a), len(b))`